# How to read the same excel file in multi thread using java?

Tags: java, excel, multithreading

Wanted to know how to read the same `Excel` file in java using multi-thread. I tried reading the Excel file using `XSSFWorkbook`, but when the initialization step is executed the program is termination without even entering to `catch` or `finally` block using `testNG` framework

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class MultiThread implements Runnable {

    @BeforeSuite
    @Parameters({"masterFileName"})
    public void threadExm (String masterFileName) {
        Thread guruThread1 = new Thread("Test1");
        Thread guruThread2 = new Thread("Test2");
        guruThread1.start();
        guruThread2.start();
        System.out.println("Thread names are following:");
        System.out.println(guruThread1.getName());
        System.out.println(guruThread2.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String excelFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/inputfiles/Master.xlsx";
            FileInputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            test(wb);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void test(XSSFWorkbook wb){
        System.out.println(wb.getSheet("Sheet1").getLastRowNum());
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather `new Thread(new MultiThread(), "Test1");`, as it does implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.

Comment: tried this ```Thread guruThread1 = new Thread(new MultiThread(), "Test1");``` still not working

Comment: Theory: If testNG runs your test in a daemon thread and waits for it, your other threads will be daemon threads too and therefore terminate early. Please include something like `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon())` to verify.

Comment: ```System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());``` is returning false